# Return epoch at 30 minutes rather than 0 minutes

Tags: javascript

Currently my code rounds down at `a.setMinutes(29)` to 0 minutes. How would I make it round up to 30 mins instead so whenever a value is before the 30 minute marks, it returns the epoch at 30 minutes. I am using this function in a appointment booking system, so a user shouldn't be able to make an appointment in the past.

```
function getRoundedTime(inDate) {
        var d = new Date(); 
        if(inDate) {
          d = inDate;
        }
        var ratio = d.getMinutes() / 60;
        // Past 30 min mark, return epoch at +1 hours and 0 minutes
        if(ratio > 0.5){
            return (d.getHours() + 1) * 3600;
        }
        // Before 30 minute mark, return epoch at 0 minutes
        if(ratio < 0.5) {
             return d.getHours() * 3600;
        }
        // Right on the 30 minute mark, return epoch at 30 minutes
        return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;
}

var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
var c = new Date();
a.setMinutes(29);
b.setMinutes(30);
c.setMinutes(31);

var aNode = document.createTextNode("Time at " + a.getMinutes() + " minutes yields: " + getRoundedTime(a) + ", ");
var bNode = document.createTextNode("Time at " + b.getMinutes() + " minutes yields: " + getRoundedTime(b) + ", ");
var cNode = document.createTextNode("Time at " + c.getMinutes() + " minutes yields: " + getRoundedTime(c));

var target = document.getElementById("t");
target.appendChild(aNode);
target.appendChild(bNode);
target.appendChild(cNode);

<div id="t">

</div>
```

I've tried to change the code to this:

```
// Before 30 minute mark, return epoch at 30 minutes

   if(ratio < 0.5) {
        return ((d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800)
   }
```

However, if the time is 10:04, it returns the epoch at +1 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: I don't understand, in code there is a comment where you say _"Before 30 minute mark, return epoch at 0 minutes"_

Comment: Just remove the block `if(ratio < 0.5) {...}` so you'll get either full hour (if it's past `hh:30`) or half hour (if it's before or exactly `hh:30`). Right? https://jsfiddle.net/4nw1dnjx/

Comment: For some reason, it rounds up to 11:30 if the time is 10:11. Is there something wrong with the rest of my code: http://pastebin.com/2Dw7JHCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'm understanding your question.
You want 09:12am to be rounded up to 09:30am so users can only pick in intervals?

```
if(ratio < 0.5) {
     return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;
}
```

I assume this function takes anything less than 30 mins and returns it as 0 mins E.g. 09:12am = 09:00am? So why not just add half an hour to it if that's the desired outcome?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I have tried your code and for some reason it rounds it up to 20 mins instead of 30 mins.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that quickly, half 3600 is 1800 not 1200 :)

Comment: Using `return (d.getHours() * 3600) + 1800;` returns the epoch at 1h30 mins, so if the time is 10:00, it returns it as 11:30.

Comment: Hmm, then try +600 instead of +1800.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what do you think is causing this. I've pasted my full code here: http://pastebin.com/2Dw7JHCC

Comment: Hmm, then try +600 instead of +1800. > Ok now if the time is 10:00, it returns it as 10:10.

Comment: @methuselah If your are doing what I thing, remember that `new Date()`  is now, Here it is 11:12, setting the minute only will set it to 11:04 so the result should be 11:30 ;)

Comment: @AxelH He declares the new date then discards it if the function has data passed to it.

Comment: The 3 dates created ;) he test by passing these dates, with only the minutes updated, so if you running his snippet now, this work with your code (which is his if minute = 30)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer, this is just some improvment, Kershrew has the correct way.

```
function getRoundedTime(inDate) {
        var d = new Date(); 
        if(inDate) {
             d = inDate;
        }
        //If ratio > .5, return next hours (our + 1)
        // if ratio <= .5 return current hours + 30minutes (half hour)
        return (d.getHours() + (ratio > 0.5 ? 1 : 0.5)) * 3600;
}
```

This should work, it add an half hour if the minute are 30 or below or an hour if more that 30.